# Как правильно отсутствИЕ паспорта (не относится к личному документы);

Tags: окончания

Изготовитель рекламации не принимает и претензии не рассматривает в случаях, если: 
- отсутствИЕ паспорта;

Answer (score 1):

> *в случаях, если:*
>
> -- отсутству**ет** паспорт изделия;

либо:

> *в случаях:*
>
> -- отсутств**ия** паспорта изделия;